# What is the difference between if (cin >> x) and if (!(cin >> x).fail())?

Tags: c++

Is there a difference between these two? I know that one returns the stream to the `if` while the other returns a boolean right away, but is there a functional difference or are they equivalent?

Comment: Depends, what is `x`?

Comment: See the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) (at the bottom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the expression `cin >> x` performs an input operation that might update `x`, and as its expression result returns a reference to the stream, i.e. to `cin`. So `cin` is being used directly as a condition. That invokes a conversion to boolean, which is defined such that it on its own is equivalent to `!cin.fail()` (i.e., the expression `cin >> x` as condition is equivalent to writing `!(cin >> x).fail()` or, as a comma expression, `(cin >> x, !cin.fail())`.